# is FileUtils.moveDirectory(src,dst) safe to move files between directories

Tags: java, file

I have to move huge files in server from one folder to another, I am using

`FileUtils.moveDirectory(src, dst);`

This is quick because `moveDirectory` just renames the `src` to `dst`, in some cases where `dst` is sub folder of `src`, it copies files to `dst` and removed from `src`(which will never happen in my case `dst` is never subdirectory of `src`).

Now, is there a chance that `FileUtils.moveDirectory(src, dst);` fails, if yes, will I have my files in source ? because this is the only copy and I cannot loose files. Either completely move to `dst` or just fail and leave my files at `src`.

Comment: All software comes with a disclaimer; in this case it could fail, your files could be partially moved, there isn't any atomic guarantee on moving files across **drives**. Now if it's all on a single drive it should be an atomic inode operation.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Yes; even if something goes wrong, the files will be in `src`.

At a low level the action is copy and then delete, rather than rename.  That way the code can insure that in no case will things be deleted before being moved; conceptually this means that the file may not exist in the `dest`(out of disk space), or may exist both at `src` and `dest` (delete permission denied), but never missing.  Also means that for a short period of time you'll be using 2x the disk space, so bear that in mind.

Source code for [FileUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/src-html/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html): see line 2881